# Apple hosted In-App purchase selective download

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

When using Apple hosted In-App purchase, is there any way to selectively download content, even though all content has been purchased? Let's say user purchased a set of PDF files, which contains hundreds of categorized PDFs, with total size over 100MB, but user only want to download some of them at any given time. Then he may delete or leave it and download more files. Does IAP API provide such selective way of downloading content from Apple hosted servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can set one package for one IAP product.

The only solution I can think of (With out using an other server), is to use the new "free" products that has been added in iOS7.

If that is possible you can set a free product for every PDF file, and enable the "purchase" and don't show this products to the users. And then when the user buys the "All PDF's" product, you can show them the list of the free products and allow them to get them.

The downside is that they will have to pass the "Free Purchase" process for each file.

Comment: Free purchase is bad option since it will bound me to iOS7 only. I never used hosted IAP, but when you upload content to Apple, do they require a single file or it can be folder structure?

Comment: I have stated in my answer that this feature was added is iOS7. You are basically uploading a .pkg file. This is one file but inside you can have you own file structure. If you want to support iOS 6 I am afraid you will have to use your own server. You can check out Parse.com for a simple solution.

Comment: If not using Parse.com, do I understand correctly that in order to achieve selective download within single purchase, I have to setup my own server for content with purchase validation mechanism with apple, then send request to my server each time user want to download one of the items.

Comment: If you want to verify the purchase every time the user wants to download one of the PDF's then yes, you will need to validate the receipt with apple (from the device or mediated by your server). Explain your self more clearly if you want more info.

Comment: I will do some research first on self-hosted solution and post new question, as it will go out of the scope of this one. thanks for this answer indeed.

Comment: Is it possible not to show: you want to get it as free? alert when user clicked on individual pdf file